# python: how to give a input list from a file to tarfile?

Tags: python, tarfile

Is there a parameter for giving input list from a list file to tar file?

I known in cli "-T"  parameter can do this,
but tarfile.py has something like that?

I use subprocess but i want to handle it without cli 'tar' command.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to use the `subprocess` module or the `tarfile` module? Please clarify it in the question.

Comment: No. the `tarfile` module is for programming, and is not a end-user program like `tar(1)`. So if you want such a feature you'll have to program it.

Comment: Currently, I use subprocess but I want to handle it without cli 'tar' command.

Comment: Thanks Carpetsmoker. I research for writing own methods.